# Não consigo perceber qual a causa deste erro

Tags: python, pygame

Estou a fazer um projecto em python do jogo quatro em linha e tenho a função valor que me diz qual o valor que esta colocado num certo ponto da tabela.

```
grelha = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
fim = False
vencedor = None
jogador = 1
linha_vitoria = None
jogo = (grelha, fim, vencedor, jogador, linha_vitoria)


def valor(jogo, linha, coluna):
'valor'
##    grelha = jogo[0]
##    jogador_1 = 1
##    jogador_2 = 2
##    valor = 0
##
##    if grelha[linha][coluna] == 1:
##        valor = 1
##    elif grelha[linha][coluna] == jogador_2:
##        valor = 2
##    else:
##        valor = 0
##
##    return valor

    linha = linha - 1
    coluna = coluna - 1

    grelha = jogo[0]

    return grelha[linha][coluna]
```

Depois tenho o modo gráfico que vai usar o pygame para criar o gráfico do jogo e uso a função valor para obter numa dada posição da tabela qual peça colocar se amarela ou vermelha.

```
def construir_frame_jogo():

    # a frame de jogo é sempre construída para o jogador humano. O
    # computador joga imediatamente a seguir ao jogador humano no
    # evento da jogada do jogador humano.

    global nova_frame

    # criar uma nova frame
    nova_frame = pygame.Surface(tamanho)

    # cor de fundo
    nova_frame.fill(cor_fundo)

    linha        = 1
    coluna_mouse = get_coluna_mouse()
    peca         = ordem_escolhida
    if ha_espaco(jogo, coluna_mouse):
        desenha_peca_jogo(linha, coluna_mouse, peca)

    for l in range(6):
        for c in range(7):

            peca = valor(jogo, l+1, c+1)
            desenha_peca_jogo(l+1+1, c+1, peca)

    # processar jogada
    if mouse_click == True:
        processar_jogada()
```

Mas quando corro o código[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] dá-me o seguinte erro e não consigo perceber porque.
Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Não consegui reparar onde você definiu o objeto `jogo`

Comment: Já coloquei a o jogo

Answer (score 1):

O seu erro:

```
 return grelha[linha][coluna]
 TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Indica que nesta linha está tentando acessar um elemento contido dentro de um objeto `int`, como se ele fosse uma lista. Como ele não é lista, retorna esse erro.

Isso só deixa duas possibilidades: ou `grelha` é `int` (e você está tentando acessar o `[linha]` nele)  ou `grelha[linha]` é `int` (e você está tentando acessar o `[coluna]` nele.

Da forma que foi definido, no pedaço de código que você colou, `grelha` é `jogo[0]`:

```
grelha = jogo[0]
```

E `jogo[0]` é a lista de listas:

```
grelha = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
jogo = (grelha, fim, vencedor, jogador, linha_vitoria)
```

Logo, não deveria dar esse erro. Eu não consigo reproduzi-lo aqui. Ao tentar rodar um código parecido com o seu, completando o que falta, funciona perfeitamente aqui.

A única explicação é que, na parte do código que você omitiu da pergunta, tem alguma redefinição ou modificação de alguma dessas variáveis, que estaria colocando/passando um objeto do tipo `int` no lugar da lista.

Caso não consiga achar o problema com a explicação acima, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/349937/edit) a sua pergunta e acrescente um [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); Isso vai permitir que eu possa testar aqui e encontrar o problema.